# why is $f(x) -f(a) = f'(a) (x-a) + \int_a^{x}f''(u)(x-u)du$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Im looking at a decomposition from [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27626/carr-madan-formula)

It states:

For a sufficiently smooth function $f$, positive constant $a$, and $x>0$,
Note that,

\begin{align*}
f(x) -f(a) &= \int_a^{x} f'(v) dv \\
&= \int_a^{x} \big[f'(v) -f'(a) + f'(a) \big] dv \\
&= f'(a) (x-a) + \int_a^{x}\!\! \int_a^v f''(u)du dv\\
&= f'(a) (x-a) + \int_a^{x}\!\! \int_u^{x} f''(u)dv du\\
&= f'(a) (x-a) + \int_a^{x}f''(u)(x-u)du.
\end{align*}

I don't understand what's happening going from the third to the fourth line. How are the limits of integration changed here? Is this change of variables? What's happening?

Comment: There was a change of the order of integration. As a result, the integration bounds have changed. Usually we have to be familiar with the function being integrated, in many cases making a plot helps. I am not sure there is a general rule you could apply.

Comment: Did we apply Fubini's theorem?

Comment: I am not familiar with this theorem. However here is an example of limit change: https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/m408s/m408d/CurrentWeb/LM15-3-6.php

Answer (score 1):

The integral
$\int_a^{x}\!\! \int_a^v f''(u)du dv
$
has $v$ going from
$a$ to $x$
and $u$ going from
$a$ to $v$.

We can write this as
$a \le u \le v \le x$.

This is the same as
$u$ going from
$a$ to $x$
and
$v$ going from
$u$ to $x$,
so the integral becomes
$\int_a^{x}\int_u^x f''(u)dv du
$.

Note that the region of integration
is a triangle,
and the two forms of the integral
involve integration in two ways:
horizontal first, then vertical,
and
vertical first then horizontal.